# Levenberg-Marquadt step search using fsolve

Tags: matlab, optimization, levenberg-marquardt

I am trying to code the Levenberg-Marquadt algorithm, I am stuck on searching for the step. Below is an image of the algorithm

[image]

I am just trying to implement fsolve in matlab to find sk, however, when I look at the documentation on the matlab website, it says I need a function of the form of F(s) =0. That is most obviously written as

F(s) = (Jk^T Jk + lambk I)s + Jk^T rk

However, fsolve doesn't like this input

Comment: You should interpret that step as: solve As=b (linear system).

Comment: If you are sugesting I should use mldivide \, unfortunately it doesn't work, and its giving me some really large condition numbers.

Comment: sk = linsolve(Jk'*Jk + lamb*eye(3,3),Jk'*rk); also gives me massive condition numbers, yielding terrible incoherent results of NaN for everything

Comment: LM attempts to solve an L2 norm minima only. When you evaluate the function with a sample point, does it output only 1 value or does it output a vector of values? Also, are you giving it the jacobian manually or is it calculated empirically?